# AJAX enabled WCF service for cascading dropdown method 404 error

Tags: ajax, wcf, http-status-code-404

I am new to WCF issues and I'm trying to populate an  control  by using a wcf service . I have used 'Ajax-Enabled WCF' template ( VS 2010) for creating my service. there is no error while on Asp.net development server  but when put on IIS [Method 404 Error] appears  in dropdown . I tried to access the WCF services  directly like (https://sitename/webservice/test.svc) it shows the documentation page.

I have searched for hours to find a solution but no  use. I will be thankful if anyone can help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to your IIS hosted service via WcfTestClient (see under Tools)? Also check the endpoint address in App.config on your client...If that does not work, could you post client's App.config and Web.config from Service's IIS?

Comment: I am able to add the service from WCF client. but i am not able to  create the  proxy class from java scrip..  since i am using the service for javascript i dont have app.config . i am unable post my web.config here due to  space limitations here.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, where it worked on dev server, but not Integration (got 404, service is not defined error).
The issue was the .svc file type was not mapped in IIS, which fixed the issue.